# oEmbded with wp_insert_post() [embedly]

Tags: wp-insert-post, embed, oembed

I try to add articles via wp_insert_post but as it seems the oEmbed function of Wordpress doesn't work properly.

I work with embedly as you can embed any website.

I realized that the oEmbed functionallity is triggered after saving the post in the Wordpress-Backend.

Can i trigger the Embed somehow programmaticly?

Wrap the URL with the Shortcode [embed] is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on [Embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds).

To trigger an embed use [`wp_oembed_get($url)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get).

In general the url needs to be on it's own line with a space below and above when inside the_content. [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) has nothing to do with embeds as the embed HTML is usually generated when passed through [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter.

To add support for non-oEmbed sites use [`wp_embed_register_handler()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler)

And for oEmbed-enabled sites use [`wp_oembed_add_provider()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider).

Answer (score 1):

I was just thinking about your support ticket when I found this question, thanks for letting us know about this. I work at Embedly and am the primary author of the embedly plugin.

I'm pretty sure @jgraup is correct that you need to utilize the wp_oembed_get function (this is called automatically when editing in the tinyMCE post editor).  If you're using the embedly plugin we will already be registered as the default oEmbed provider.  I will try to test myself asap.

-Chris